# How to load the url in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have a problem regarding to jquery and jsp. I used a jquery `load()` to load the data on the same page but the main problem was when it was loading the url remains same as the home page but i want to change the url to what the data i have clicked. I already used meta refresh tag but it not working on jsp pages so Please help me to complete the task that to paste the url what the page i have been clicked.I used html tags and javasript and jquery which was saved in jsp pages.

Comment: This will help: http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html‎

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **window.history.pushState** :

```
window.history.pushState({},'',"http://newurl.com");
```

and on **jQUery .load** example :

```
$("#div").load("http://mysite.com/newpage",function(){
 window.history.pushState({},'newpage', "http://mysite.com/newpage");
});
```

And if you want to change the title of document as well, use :

```
document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML = 'New Page';
window.history.pushState({},'newpage','http://mysite.com/newpage' );
```

Comment: Thank You Sir it was working but it was raised an other problem that all the pages doesn't have the menu bar when we refresh it was loading without the menu and the other head tags.So please rectify the problem too sir thanks for giving reply.

Answer (score 1):

If you're concerned about compatibility towards older browsers and the more modern (although outdated) versions of IE, you have little choice that I'm aware of but either using a redirect which triggers an entire page load, or use the hash sign, which you can access via

```
document.location.hash
```

If you're not concerned about that, have a look at the HTML5 history API (http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html)

It's as simple as

```
history.pushState(null, null, 'newURL')
```

And doesn't break compatibility with the browsers back and forward buttons, provided your page takes those into account.